# If $f$ is isometric in a limited subset $C \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ which $\partial C$ has measure null, then $vol(f(C)) = vol(C)$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, volume, change-of-variable

If $f: \mathbb{R}^n \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is isometric in a $C \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ limited subset which $\partial C$ has measure null, then $vol \ f(C) = vol (C)$.

> $\textbf{My attempt:}$
>
> I apply the Theorem of Change of Variables to obtain that $\int_{f(C)} g =
> > \int_C (g \circ f) |det \ f'|$ and, assuming that $g = \chi_{f(C)}$, we have 
>   $\int_{f(C)} 1 = \int_C 1 \ |det \ f'|$, i.e., $vol(f(C)) = \int_C 1 \ |det \  f'|$.

My doubts about this attempt are:

$\textbf{1.}$ I need to show that $f: int(C) \longrightarrow f(int(C))$ is a $C^1-$ isomorphism to apply the Theorem of Change of Variables, but I don't know how I can show this.

$\textbf{2.}$ I need to show that $|det f'(x)| = 1$ for each point $x$ in $C$, but I don't know how I can show this.

I think that I must use the fact that $||f(x) - f(y)|| = ||x - y||$ for each point $x, y \in C$ to solve my doubts. Someone can help me? Thanks in advance!

EDIT :

I know that alinear transformation $A$ is orthogonal when $A^T = A^{-1}$. If $f'$ is an orthogonal linear transformation, then $det \ f' = det \ f'^T = det (f')^{-1}$. Since $det f' \circ (f')^{-1} = det f * det f'^{-1}$, $det f' \circ (f')^{-1} = det Id$ and $det \ f' = det f'^T$, we have $|det f'| = 1$. I thought about this, but I don't see how the fact of $f$ be isometric, imply that $f'$ is an orthogonal matrice.

Comment: I think the isometric condition can imply $f$ is a linear map.

Comment: By the way, what does the "limited subset" mean? Does it mean it is closed?

Comment: means that for every $x \in C$, exist $r > 0$ such that $C \subset B(x,r)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isometries from $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ have determinant $\pm1$. This is due to the fact that the set of orthogonal matrices form the isometry group of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Hence, since $D_pf$ is a linear map, the underlying matrix or jacobian $J$ is orthogonal i.e $JJ^T = I$ and so $\textbf{det}(J) ^2= 1$.

Comment: I understood, thanks!